# How so I put these in Standard form? Circle, Ellipse or Hyperbola?

Tags: conic-sections

I need help putting these into standard form so I can graph them. Also need help figuring out which ones are which:

$$25x^2-16y^2-150x+64y-239=0$$

$$9x^2+4y^2+54x-64y+301=0$$

$$x^2+y^2-6x+8y+3=0$$

Comment: Do you know how to [complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)?

Comment: So .. can over-eager solvers wait for thxll to return and respond to Hakim?

Comment: Hakim's right.  But I just want to point out that the first thing you should look for in these types of problems is if the quadratic is *slanted*.  You'll be able to tell it is if there appear any $xy$ terms.  There aren't any here, but **The** **More** **You** **Know** $\star$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  As Hakim suggests, complete the square to get the standard parameters out.  Like this (you fill in the question marks):

$$25x^2-16y^2-150x+64y-239 =0 \\ (25x^2 - 150x\;+\;?)-(16y^2-64y\;+\;?) -239\;+\;? =0 \\ 25(x\;+\;?)^2 - 16(y\;+\;?)^2 - 239\;+\;? =0 $$